# bounds of spectral radius of hadamard product

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

In Topics in matrix analysis by R. A. Horn, C. J. Johnson it's shown that for two positive matrices $A$ and $B$, $\rho(A\circ B)<\rho(A)\rho(B)$. 
I'm wondering whether the extension of this to positive linear operators is an established result. And is there any restrictions I should worry about?

For instance, $T_1(f)=\int k_1(x,y)f(y)dy$, $T_2(f)=\int k_2(x,y)f(y)dy$ for some strictly positive, square integrable kernels $k_1$ and $k_2$, do we naturally have $\rho(T_1\circ T_2)<\rho(T_1)\rho(T_2)$ where $T_1\circ T_2(f)=\int k_1(x,y)k_2(x,y)f(y)dy$

Comment: I don't think that having $k_1$ and $k_2$ strictly positive implies that $T_1$, $T_2$ are positive operators in $L^2$ sense. Even for matrices, a matrix $A$ with positive entries is not necessarily positive, that is, it might happen that $x^t Ax<0$ for some vector $x$.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro thank you for your comment, yet I don't mean positive definite here.

Comment: Ah ok, so "positive" here means that $Tf(x)\ge 0$ whenever $f(x)\ge 0$ I guess.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro, I just mean the simplest interpretation of "positive". For matrices that's positive entries; for integral operators that's positive kernel.

Comment: It is clear, I am sorry for my pointless comments. Unfortunately I have no idea about the answer to your interesting question.

Comment: I think there may be problems with the analogue of the Hadamard product $T_{1}\circ T_{2}$ regarding the domain. If $k_{1},k_{2}\in L^{2}[0,1]^{2}$, then it is not necessarily true that $k_{1}k_{2}\in L^{2}[0,1]^{2}$. For example, take $k_{1}(x,y)=k_{2}(x,y)=\left|x-y\right|^{-1/2}$.